# What is the username and password to use after installation of Kubuntu or Ubuntu?

Tags: login

I have installed Kubuntu on my laptop while logged into ubuntu, after it restarted kubuntu login came up, what is the username and password for this.

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, or Lubuntu with the installation ISOs that are readily-downloadable for the end user (the ISOs on releases.ubuntu.com for example), and not any other specialized installation types, the installer asks you for the Username and Password you want the primary user to have.

If you did see this during installation, then use the information you provided.

If you did not specify this, or you were not the one who set up the system, than you should refer to [this question and its corresponding answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) in order to solve how to reset the lost passwords.

You can find out your username in this method, by mounting the Ubuntu disk inside a LiveUSB and see what usernames are available on the system in the `/home` directory as the default-installed users are always given a `/home` directory on install.

---

Alternatively, if you just wish to reinstall to provide new user data, you can do that, however in a lot of cases this is not necessary.